# Android ActionBar with custom Icons?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, material-design

I want to create a Android ActionBar which looks like the following.

[image]

**How can I build such a ActionBar. Is it possible to build it with Android material Design?**

Comment: Action bar tabs -- what you have on the left -- were deprecated as a design pattern with Android 5.0 and are not part of Material Design. The Material Design documentation [describes their tab designs](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html).

Comment: Is there anything similar to what I have show in the picture with material design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the new ToolBar from Android Design Support Library

http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Using ToolBar instead of ActionBar will give you more control on the elements themselves.

You can find a good article here:

http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-app.html

[image]

app_bar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#3F51B5"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

main_activity_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <include layout="@layout/app_bar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

main_activity_onCreate()

```
toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appBar);
toolBar.setTitle("Titolo");
setSupportActionBar(toolBar);

tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.user));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.user_group_1));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.user_group_2));
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: Please explain how `Toolbar` would address the OP's issue. Just because it will "give you more control on the elements themselves" does not mean that `Toolbar` directly supports the UI that the OP is seeking, nor does it address whether this is supported by Material Design.

Comment: I think I've explained

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could stitch together such a layout with multiple elements. For example you have a header layout containing a TabLayout on the left and a Toolbar on the right side, instead of using the standard ActionBar.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This example uses the AppCompat v7 and the Design Support library.

You may style the Views in a way (e.g. same background color) such that it looks as if its one single UI element.